# Removing multiple elements from an array using JSON patch

Tags: rest, json-patch

Say I have an entity that looks like this:

```json
{
  "list": ["foo", "qux", "bar"]
}
```

If I want to remove `"foo"` and `"bar"` using one JSON patch with two operations. What is the correct syntax?

### Option 1

This option expects the indexes to be immutable while the operations are being invoked.

```json
[
  { "op": "remove", "path": "/list/0" }, // removes "foo"
  { "op": "remove", "path": "/list/2" }  // removes "bar" using original index
]
```

### Option 2

This option expects the indexes to shift after the first operation has been invoked.

```json
[
  { "op": "remove", "path": "/list/0" }, // removes "foo"
  { "op": "remove", "path": "/list/1" }  // removes "bar" using new index
]
```

### Option 3

This option expects unexpected behavior could occur and guards itself.

```json
[
  { "op": "remove", "path": "/list/2" }, // removes "bar" first to ignore shifting indexes
  { "op": "remove", "path": "/list/0" }  // removes "foo"
]
```

Option 3 is the safest option, I'm just mostly curious about what is correct. The [RFC for JSON patch](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6902/#section-4.2) isn't clear on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The remove method on array members has implementation-dependent behaviour with relation to indexes, according the **JSON Patch specification RFC 6902**.

As a result, all three of your suggestions are feasible and contingent on how they are implemented. It's important to note that **option 1** implies the immutability of the indexes, which is not necessarily the case.

**Option 2** moves the indexes after the initial operation, which is a typical strategy and presupposes that the indexes are malleable. By eliminating the piece with the higher index first, **Option 3** prevents problems with index shifting.

It is advised to select **option 3** or **2** if the order of the array's members is not crucial. The safest option is **3**, as it prevents any potential index shifting problems. When the order of the remaining components is crucial and you're certain that the index shifting won't create any problems, you should select **option 2**, which is shorter.